# Can't generate class getters dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular component which implements this simple interface:

```
export interface Form {
  form: FormGroup;
}
```

Now, the goal is to create a mixin or decorator that generates the getters for the FormGroup controls. This mixin can only be applied to those classes that implement the Form interface. But when I try to use it in my component, my IDE doesn't even suggest the methods.

**Here's my mixin:**

```
export const formGroupGetters = <T extends { new(...args: any[]): Form }>(constructor: T) => {
  return class extends constructor {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      for(const controlName in this.form.controls){
        Object.defineProperty(this, controlName+"Control", {
          get: () => this.form.controls[controlName] as FormControl
        });
      }
    }
  };
}
```

**And here's my component file:**

```
const Mixin = formGroupGetters(
  class Parent implements Form {
    form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      username: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      name: new FormControl(""),
      newsletter: new FormControl(false)
    });
  }
);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class RegisterComponent extends Mixin {
  error?: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }

  submit() { ... }
}
```

**Side note:** I'm kind of new to mixins and decorators, so feel free to suggest any improvement for their application.

Comment: I'd guess that "Form" is probably a reserved word.  I'd use a more unique name for that interface.  (beyond that, it's over my head...)